# Let $F: V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Assume $F(v_1),...,F(v_n)$ are linearly independent. Show that $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

My solution:

Assume that $F(v_1),F(v_2),...F(v_n)$ are linearly independent, so $α_1F(v_1) + α_2F(v_2) + ... + α_nF(v_n)=0$ only and only if $α_1=α_2=...=α_n=0$.

Linear transformation is when:

i) $F(αv)=αF(v)$

ii) $F(v+w)=F(v)+F(w)$

Then $α_1F(v_1) + α_2F(v_2) + ... + α_nF(v_n) = F(α_1v_1) + ... + F(α_nv_n) = 0$, I used i)

By using ii) we get $F(α_1v_1+ ... + α_nv_n)=0$

We know that $0 = F(0)$ so:

$F(α_1v_1 + ... + α_nv_n) = F(0) => α_1v_1 + ... + α_nv_n = 0$, so $v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent

My teacher says it's wrong and I should do it again but I can't find a mistake :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are saying $F(v)=0 \implies v=0$, this is true only if $F$ is injective.

Comment: You know that $F(0)=0$ ,but do you know that if $F(v)=0$ then $v=0$? do you that $0$ is the only element in $V$ that maps to $0$? in fact for linear transformation F , $ker(F)=\{v \in V| F(v)=0\} = \{0\} \iff $ F is injective.

Comment: Apart from anything else, if you want to prove that some vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent, then at the very least your argument should start "suppose $\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots = 0$."  You don't do that, so it's not even clear what your $\alpha_i$s are supposed to be.  Also, you are given an assumption (that certain vectors are LI).  If you never use that assumption, what you've done can't possibly be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already you made the mistake that you claimed the following: if for any $v \in V$ we have $F(v) =0$ then $v=0$. But this is only true if $F$ is injective, or equivalently if $\ker(F) = \{0\}$. So we cannot use this in this case.

Now we want to prove that given $a_1, \dots, a_n \in F$ (where $F$ is the underlying field of the vector spaces $V$ and $W$) we have that
$$a_1v_1+ \dots + a_nv_n=0 \Rightarrow a_1= \dots = a_n=0.$$
(this is the definition of linear independence of the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$).

In any reasonable exercise you should somehow use the assumption. So there has to be a point in our proof where we use that $F(v_1), \dots, F(v_n)$ are linearly independent. Let's start:

For the sake of contradiction assume that there is a non-trivial linear combination (non-trivial meaning that at least one coefficient $b_i$ is non-zero) of the $v_i$ that gives zero, i.e.
$$b_1v_1+ \dots b_nv_n=0 \text{ and at least one } b_i \ne 0.$$
(We now want to arrive at a contradiction because this assumption would mean that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is linearly dependent).
Now from basic facts on linear operators we know that $F(0)=0$, therefore
$$0=F(0) = F(b_1v_1 + \dots b_nv_n) = b_1F(v_1) + \dots b_nF(v_n)$$
by properties 1. and 2. listed by you.
But if we compare the left hand side and the right hand side we have a linear combination of the vectors $F(v_1), \dots, F(v_n)$ giving zero, namely
$$0=b_1F(v_1) + \dots b_nF(v_n).$$
But remember: at least one $b_i$ is non-zero, so there is a non-trivial linear combination of $F(v_1), \dots, F(v_n)$ which gives zero. This is a contradiction of the assumption that $F(v_1), \dots, F(v_n)$ are linearly independent.

Hence our initial assumption must have been wrong and $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are linearly independent.